# KeyboarddAvoidingView not working with keyboard on bottom

Tags: react-native, layout

I have a component that renders the following:

```
return (
  <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="position">
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.messagesContainer}>
      </View>
      <SafeAreaView>
        <View style={styles.inputView}>
          <TextInput style={styles.input} />
          <Button title="submit" />
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </View>
  </KeyboardAvoidingView>
)
```

With stylesheet:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    height: "100%"
  },
  messagesContainer: {
    backgroundColor: "red",
    flex: 1
  },
  inputView: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    padding: 5,
    height: 24
  },
  input: {
    height: 20,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    flex: 1
  }
});
```

This view is rendered as a screen in a react-navigation `StackNavigation`.

I'd like the view to move up to make space for the keyboard, but it doesn't seem to move up far enough.

[image]

I know it's moving it up, because if I add some padding to the bottom of my container:

[image]

I've also wondered whether the SafeArea component is messing up the calculations of how far up the view should be moved, but it doesn't seem so.

[image]

I could tweak that bottom padding until the text input shows up right above the keyboard, but that seems like a flaky solution that'd require different values for different devices, orientations, keyboard layouts, etc.

Is there a more robust solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need some modification in styling try this

```
return (
  <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="position" style={styles.containerWraper}>
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.messagesContainer}>

      </View>
      <SafeAreaView>
        <View style={styles.inputView}>
          <TextInput style={styles.input} />
          <Button title="submit" />
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </View>
  </KeyboardAvoidingView>
)
```

### Styles

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  containerWraper:{
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  messagesContainer: {
    backgroundColor: "red",
    flex: 1
  },
  inputView: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    padding: 5,
    height: 24
  },
  input: {
    height: 20,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    flex: 1
  }
});
```

Comment: This seems to not work either. See screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qyy1ffc3nmumo59/Screenshot%202018-02-02%2010.39.58.png?dl=0 It looks like `flex:1`is not causing messagesContainer to take up the expected height.

Comment: Just to make sure I made the right changes; you changed `container`, and added `containerWrapper` for the KeyboardAvoiding view, right? just so I'm not overlooking any changes.

Answer (score -1):

Try NativeBase instead, that has better approach